# Can't get stylesheet to show up in ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, blueprint-css

I have the following code in my application.erb file in my layouts directory. I have the blueprint directory inside of public/stylesheets however the link doesn't work. It says it is supposed to be located at `<link href="/assets/blueprint/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` But There is nothing there.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %>
```

Comment: Place your stylesheets in `assets` folder and see

Comment: I know the answer to this question, but I have been asked by the stack overflow people not to reference my own code.  SORRY...  hint look into config/production.rb the asset pipeline by default only compiles application.js and application.css in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/blueprint/screen" %>`  & place your `screen.css` in the following heirarchy:

`app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css`

Comment: As a third party resource I think that blueprint belongs in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/blueprint`.