# Why isn't my images and stylesheets not working in RoR app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Sorry for the dumb question, but I spent 2 days trying and nothing solved the issue. My problem is that I need to "simply edit a file with your HTML and your app will work". Sounds easy, but so far it's impossible for me!

I have this in application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "core.css", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/turnkey/style.css" %>
```

Just in case, [I followed this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123661/cant-get-stylesheet-to-show-up-in-ruby-app) solutions, but it did nothing for me. `core.css` works fine, but `/turnkey/style.css` is 404.

My style.css file is indeed there, you can see a screen capture (sorry, I can't add images):
[enter link description here](http://i60.tinypic.com/2e3bhpg.png)

I tried clearing cache, tried restarting server but nothing. Tried placing the `style.css` file in  `assets/stylesheets` and nothing

One thing I have noticed is that the original `core.css` always shows up. Even if I replace it with the contents of `style.css` , it displays the content of the original `core.css` so I thought about a cache issue, thus used the solution at http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-a-page-in-rails/

```
..in application_controller.rb..
  before_filter :set_cache_buster
  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

But still couldn't fix it.

Additionally, my images at app/assets/images show as 404 as well, even though I'm uploading them to the same folder the original images are. Old images are OK, new images don't show, as if they were never uploaded

In short, I'm totally lost. Sorry for the probably stupid question, but I just don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSS take out `/` from beginning of the path:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "turnkey/style.css" %>`

This way Rails prepends `assets/stylesheets` to the path automatically. If you add a `/` in the beginning, Rails thinks that you are providing full path.

Similarly for images in `assets/images` folder, all you need is to use this:

`<%= image_tag "image_filename" %>`

Replace `image_filename` with full name of your image file (including ext in most cases).

For more in-depth details, read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: I did what you said and now the style.css file becomes `/assets/turnkey/style-37aa0af098ffe9b4616c5467a5104fbe.css` but still 404. The images code I'm using is exactly the same as you say (I just replaced the original images with my own), yet nothing seems to work

Comment: You may have some messed up configuration. Please make sure you are running the app in dev mode, and please post the contents of development.rb file from config/envorinments folder.